# Can't update Connected account with token

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.js

I tried to update a Connected Account using token like this :

```
$account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve($_POST['stripe_connect_edd_user']);
$account->account_token = $_POST['token_stripe_edd'];
$account->save();
```

But I've got this error :

> Once a full set of basic legal entity information has been provided
>   (type, business_name, first_name, last_name, and address), you cannot
>   unset any of it, only update it.

The token is generated exactly like account creation, and Stripe Logs seems OK :

[image]

Any idea about what's wrong ?

Comment: It means that you created your account with the legal entity information.

Comment: Exact. But what is the problem ?

Comment: @GildasRoss The issue is that the account is already verified so you can not update all the information again and you have to explicitly only update what is missing on that account and nothing else.